# Sort nested divs alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have the following div layout:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="title">World</div>
        <div class="description">text1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="entry">
        <div class="title">hello</div>
        <div class="description">text2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="entry">
        <div class="title">Lorem</div>
        <div class="description">text3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to sort the `entry` divs alphabetically by the content of the child `title` div.

### What I've tried so far

This will sort it alphabetically:

```
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.title').sort(function(a, b) {
            return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).text().toLowerCase(), $(b).text().toLowerCase());
        });

var container = $(".container");
container.detach().empty().append(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
$('body').append(container);
```

But it will strip the `description` divs. Try [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yapu9a6m/).

How can I sort the divs alphabetically without stripping anything?

Comment: We need to see more of these `What I've tried so far` sections. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is correct, but the issue is you're sorting the `.title` elements. Instead you need to sort the `.entry` elements, and then find the `.title` within the current `.entry` and perform the comparison on their text values. Try this:

```js
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.entry').sort(function(a, b) {
  var $aTitle = $(a).find('.title'), $bTitle = $(b).find('.title');
  return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($aTitle.text().toLowerCase(), $bTitle.text().toLowerCase());
});

var container = $(".container");
container.detach().empty().append(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
$('body').append(container);
```

```css
.entry {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="entry">
    <div class="title">World</div>
    <div class="description">text1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="entry">
    <div class="title">hello</div>
    <div class="description">text2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="entry">
    <div class="title">Lorem</div>
    <div class="description">text3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I sort the divs alphabetically without stripping anything?

By sorting the *right* elements?

Why are you sorting `.title`, if as you stated the `.entry` elements are what you actually want to sort?

```
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.entry').sort(function(a, b) {
            return String.prototype.localeCompare.call(
              $(a).find('.title').text().toLowerCase(), 
              $(b).find('.title').text().toLowerCase());
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yapu9a6m/1/

Answer (score 1):

You just have to take the parent element with you when you sort. Then you go searching the child element after which you want to sort:

```
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.entry').sort(function(a, b) {
        return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).find("div.title").text().toLowerCase(), $(b).find("div.title").text().toLowerCase());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting the titles,  you should be sorting the entries.

So 1 tiny change:

```
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.entry').sort(function(a, b) {
        return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).text().toLowerCase(), $(b).text().toLowerCase());
    });
```

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yapu9a6m/3/)

Comment: this is not working when the title element is not the first child